# Value for 'keystore' is not valid. It must resolve to a single path

Tags: android, command-line, apk

i am trying to build apk from command line with ant. I am able to create build in debug mode while getting this error when i run in release mode for signing the apk file with the key store generated.

my local.properties file look like this

```
sdk.dir=E:\\_WorkArea\\adt-bundle-windows-x86\\sdk
key.store=C:\Users\\l.keystore
key.alias=tys
key.store.password=tr
key.alias.password=tre 


  D:\Android-Sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:1132: The following error occurred 
while executing this line:

D:\Android-Sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:1144: Value for 'keystore' is not 
valid. It must resolve to a single path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was resolved by the keystore and the project has to be on the same folder... thats what it means by saying `It must resolve to a single path`..resolved myself....kudos

Answer (score 15):

i got the same problem with you.

you miss the "\" at key.store value

Note:
**key.store=C:\\Users\\l.keystore**

Comment: no that did not work. i have already resolved it by placing the keystore file inside the project folder.

Answer (score 4):

@cavallo answer is incorrect

It is not at all mandatory for keystore to be in the same folder.
The solution for you might have worked because the relative path would contain any `slashes` to be escaped.

Don't mislead others by accepting wrong answers of yours.

Comment: @shdhir Mishra let me check

Answer (score 1):

I had this message as well. It turned out my problem was actually in the ant.properties file where the keystore path contained an error. Changing that fixed it.